# Update with CTE and row-numbers as sequence or TSQL update query with ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table named `Site` with columns `Name`, `SiteId` and `Sequence`. I would like to fill the `Sequence` field with the rownumber. I've tried the following query, but it just doesn't update the records:

```
WITH RowNumbers AS 
(
    select   SiteId,
             RowNum = row_number() OVER ( order by SiteId )
    from     [Site] 
)
UPDATE  s
SET     s.[Sequence] = r.RowNum
FROM    [Site] as s INNER JOIN RowNumbers as r ON s.SiteId = r.Row
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can update the CTE directly...

```
WITH RowNumbers AS 
(
    select   *,
             RowNum = row_number() OVER ( order by SiteId )
    from     [Site] 
)
UPDATE  RowNumbers
SET     [Sequence] = RowNum
```

This works in the same way as an updatable view.  I added `*` to ensure the the updated field comes through, and then updated it directly.

Comment: Wow... works like a charm. Is far more readable. Didn't know that.

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You should join to `r.SiteID`, not `r.Row`

```
WITH RowNumbers AS  
( 
    select   SiteId, 
             RowNum = row_number() OVER ( order by SiteId ) 
    from     [Site]  
) 
UPDATE  s 
SET     s.[Sequence] = r.RowNum 
FROM    [Site] as s INNER JOIN RowNumbers as r ON s.SiteId = r.SiteID
```